# How do i replace lines of printed text in python?

Tags: python

Basically i want to replace a printed string with another. My code reads something like:  `while True:, a += random.randint(1,2), time.sleep(1), print(a)`
This works but looks bad so i was wondering how i can replace the printed text with new text each time it prints.

Comment: You can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169217/replace-console-output-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print in one line dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249524/print-in-one-line-dynamically)

Comment: Along with the other answers and comments, you may also check the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69139037/overwriting-a-line-after-printing-out-something

Answer (score 1):

I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897359/output-to-the-same-line-overwriting-previous-output) can answer your question.
Try

```
while True:
    a += random.randint(1,2)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(a,end='\r')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace()` function.

Usage :

```
txt = "I like bananas"

x = txt.replace("bananas", "apples")

print(x)
```

```py
while True: 
  a += random.randint(1,2)
  time.sleep(1)
  print(a)
  x = replace(a, "new string")
  print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you are trying to do:

The simple answer is use the character `\r` which moves back the cursor to the begin of the line:

`print("Hello world\rAloha")` outputs ->  `Aloha world`

```
c=0
while True:
  print(c, end='\r') #remember to overwrite `end` or print will append a `\n` at the end
  c+=1
```

If you need anything more complicated consider using `curses`: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Probably even `rich` can do this kind of things but I'm not sure because I have never used it: https://pypi.org/project/rich/